# GestureOverlay view needs to override parent's(View Pager/Scroll View) Touch event

Tags: events, android-viewpager, touch, scrollview, intercept

I've spent the last couple of days reading through docs and answers trying to get a solution for this. So I resort to this, with a probability of being a duplicate, as a cry for help.

I have a GestureOverlay panel to read horizontal swipe gestures. This sits on top of a view pager. 
I need to disable the functioning of the view pager when the touch event is read on the gesture panel.

- I've extended ViewPager to let me enable and disable it with a member method.
- Overrode the onTouch event of gesture to return true (consume the event) and disallow Intercept touch event on its parent (only on action_move/down). I also tried to disable the view pager onTouch, but the viewpager's on touch event is fired first

How do I achieve this?